# Ограничить кол-во записей в группе при группировке в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый день! Есть таблица **products** полями:

**id** - PRIMARY
**manufacturer** - производитель товара INDEX
**code** - код товара INDEX
**price** - цена товара

Таблица содержит более 200 млн. наименований, у некоторых кодов производители взаимозаменяемые (т.е. один код может быть у нескольких производителей и по факту это один и тот же товар).

В чем состоит проблема:
при запросе

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE `code` = 'ABC1' ORDER BY `price` LIMIT 2000;
```

сортировка идет по цене, и допустим, что если у фирмы SONY будет около 3000 самых дешевых наименований, то остальные производители в выборку попросту не попадут. На самом деле запрос не такой простой, а занимает несколько страниц, на нем завязано много хайлоад сервисов и менять его на корню сложно, но если упростить, получится именно такой.

> ### Что я пробовал:
>
> 2 варианта хранимых процедур:
>   1) отсортировать запрос сначала по производителю, затем по цене, передать запрос в процедуру, получить курсор, в LOOP считать кол-во производителей и нужные записи вставлять в TEMPORARY TABLE, затем выбирать из нее результат. Проблема: курсор можно получить только из select_statement, динамический SQL не катит
>
> 2) передавать запрос в процедуру, заполнять запросом TEMPORARY TABLE, далее магия, на выходе которой формируется запрос вида:
>   DELETE FROM tmp_tbl WHERE manufacturer = 'SONY' LIMIT 200, 100000;
>   DELETE FROM tmp_tbl WHERE manufacturer = 'PIONEER' LIMIT 200, 100000;
>   .......
>   То есть для каждого бренда DELETE с лимитом. Но и тут проблема: DELETE в MySQL не умеет OFFSET. Он не может пропустить 200 строк, а остальные удалить

**Собственно вопрос:** как в одном запросе ограничить количество выводимых записей до 200 по производителю? Например, если у SONY 3000 наименований, то выбираются первые 200 и т.д. Производителей у одного кода может доходить до сотни.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самым простым будет пронумеровать записи в пределах производителя по порядку цен, используя переменные.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
   SELECT P.*,
          @num:=if(@man=manufacturer,@num+1,1) as NUM,
          @man:=manufacturer
     FROM products P, (select @man:='',@num:=0) A
    WHERE `code` = 'ABC1'
    ORDER BY manufacturer, `price`
  ) A
 WHERE NUM<=200
 ORDER BY price
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо!
только в следующий джоин не видит P почему-то


`SELECT *
  FROM (
   SELECT P.*,
          @num:=if(@man=manufacturer,@num+1,1) as NUM,
          @man:=manufacturer
     FROM products P, (select @man:='',@num:=0) A
        INNER JOIN sclad ON (P.sclad = sclad.id)
    WHERE `code` = 'ABC1'
    ORDER BY manufacturer, price
  ) A
 WHERE NUM<=200
 ORDER BY price`

Comment: @AlexShmalex Запятые и join смешивать не стоит. Что то типа `... FROM products P JOIN (select @man:='',@num:=0) A INNER JOIN sclad` думаю из за этого. или может местами переставить `...  (select @man:='',@num:=0) A, products P  INNER JOIN sclad`

Comment: поменять местами не получилось, а вот JOIN помог, и важно, чтобы он был самым последним