# Как сделать выборку и пронумеровать строки, от текущей даты?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица со списком пользователей, нужно сделать выборку, пронумеровать строки, от текущей даты. С учетом что 0 это текущая дата.  Второй день мучаюсь ничего не выходит. Это возможно?
[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: katya 2017-03-20 тоже 2?

Comment: в идеале, 0 это CURDATE()
А все остальные в порядке убывания по дате, но какая то дата может быть пропущена.
Поэтому katya 2017-03-20 это 1, katya 2017-03-19 это 2.
alesha 2017-03-12 не нужен т.к. нет записи от CURDATE()

Comment: 2 шага точно надо - на 1м определяете, какие имена есть для такой даты, на втором делаете выборку по этим именам. В Полученных результатах для каждого имени дату представляете как Unixtime, и сортируете от большего к меньшему.

Comment: Внутренний подзапрос из этого http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600190/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2-mysql/600200#600200 ответа посмотрите, там как раз идет нумерация в разрезе групп. В вашем случае `order by username, created_at desc`. И в where сразу выбирайте только записи с `created_at<=curdate()`

Comment: @mike Разобрался в чем ошибка, огромное спасибо
SELECT *
  FROM (
   SELECT P.*,
          @num:=if(@man=`username`,@num+1,0) as NUM,
          @man:=`username`
     FROM content P, (select @man:='',@num:=0) A
    WHERE created_at<=curdate()
    ORDER BY username, created_at desc
  ) A
 WHERE 1
 ORDER BY id

Comment: @Mike еще такой момент, а как можно встроить еще запрос 
SELECT `username` FROM `content` WHERE `created_at`=curdate()
Чтобы выводились все записи  пользователей которые оставляли запись сегодня

Comment: Встроить запрос куда ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
   SELECT P.*,
          @num:=if(@man=`username`,@num+1,0) as NUM,
          @man:=`username`
     FROM `content` P, (select @man:='',@num:=0) A
    WHERE created_at<=curdate()
    ORDER BY username, created_at desc
  ) A
 WHERE 1
 ORDER BY id
```

Спасибо, @Mike.