# поиск данных для нескольких пользователей между определенным промежутком чисел

Tags: php, mysql

```
таблица: data

user_id     max_number      expire_time
11          8               2017-04-03 17:45:17
18          9               2017-04-03 18:10:12

таблица: users

id          number
11          11.17
16          14.87
18          90.25
30          91.16
31          94.42
32          16.15
33          18.15
44          12.21
```

Для каждого `user_id` таблицы `data` требуется выбрать из таблицы `users` четыре `id` ровно (если наберется 4),
у которых `number`, (пример ID `11`) не меньше `11.17+1=12.17` и не больше `11.17+8=19.17`,
где `11.17` - занчение столбца `number` таблицы `users` для `id=11`, `+1` - общий известный порог,
а `+8` - порог `max_number` из таблицы `data` для `user_id=11` т.е. получить на выходе `id`: `44` `16` `32` `33`
После, если найдены 4 ID которые соответствуют параметрам поиска,  производится операция `INSERT` для каждого такого ID.
Это нужно выполнить одним запросом (вызовом скрипта один раз), который должен выбрать из `user_id` `11` и `18` и произвести такой поиск для каждого `user_id`.

Как правильно это реализовать?

В таблице `data` может быть и до 1.000 уникальных ID для которых требуется провести такой поиск. Значения столбца `number` таблицы `users` могут каждую минуту изменяться, правда с незначительным отклонением от предыдущего значения. Проверку требуется выполнять ежеминутно.

Comment: `Для каждого user_id таблицы data требуется выбрать из таблицы users четыре id ровно (если наберется 4)` А если наберётся больше? Вообще задача решается нумерацией записей в группах с последующим отбором по номеру в группе.

Comment: Перефразирую: если наберется больше 4х записей, то какие конкретно 4 из имеющихся надо взять. И да, задача выборки N записей по группе в MySQL решается как то так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600190/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2-mysql/600200#600200

Comment: А если нужна скорость ... Нумерация потребует полного прохода части таблицы users (которые попали в диапазон), сколько записей попавших под условие ожидается ? Удается ли оптимизировать на _ваших_ данных запрос вида `select * from users where number between 12.17 and 19.17 order by нужная_колонка limit 4` до выборки по индексу только требуемых 4х записей, без перебора половины таблицы (см. план выполнения) ? И наконец, какие данные из users потом предполагается инсертить, в каком виде и с какой дальнейшей целью

Comment: @Akina, приоритетным условием является попадание в диапазон `12.17 - 19.17` без дополнительного отбора, фактически из 10 требуется выбрать 4 случайных в этом диапазоне. Кстати, 4 не является фиксированным числом и будет изменяться в параметрах конфигурации (т.е. может быть 1).

Comment: @Mike, данный запрос выполняется через cron, после того как `user_id=11`, обратившись в ручном режиме, не нашел данные и поставил задачу на уведомление. Учитывая то, что уведомление имеет срок истечения, скрипт планируется запускать ежеминутно, при интервале в минуту не ожидается большого скопления записей попадающих под диапазон требуемый для `user_id=11`, но ожидается множество записей в `data`, каждый со своим диапазоном, который требуется прогнать по таблице `users` кол-во записей которой будет постепенно нарастать (пусть 500.000 записей, вообще предела нет). >>>>>>

Comment: @Mike, >>>>>> По оптимизации сложно сказать, так как сейчас таблицы пустые. Скорее всего отбор придется производить посредством `HAVING number >= 1 AND number <= 8`, который используется при ручном запросе пользователем `user_id=11`. Инсертить потребуется поля типа: int и datetime для связки найденных записей (1 юзер из data (поставил уведомление) + 4 из users (найденные по диапазону)).

Comment: Ну `having number ...` это вы загнули, в having нельзя использовать голые колонки, потому как он применяется после группировки. там есть смысл использовать только результаты групповых функций (sum/min/max) голые колонки есть смысл проверять только в where и on. А по поводу ещеминутной проверки не произошло ли нужных изменений ... что то мне подсказывает, что нужные проверки надо делать в триггере на изменение поля number в users и тогда ничего ежеминутного вообще не надо будет делать

Comment: @Mike, ну а как должен выглядеть запрос, выборка из `data` и потом 50 запросов в `multi_query`, если в `data` 50 уникальных записей? ну и индекс на `number`.

Comment: Что такое `multi_query` ? В триггере ... там конечно будут сложности, потому что саму users читать нельзя, значит надо будет в data хранить копию текущего number пользователя и обновлять в триггере за одно. И тогда понять интервал можно будет чисто по таблице дата и тогда даем что то типа `into into таблица_куда_идет_вставка_результатов(...) select ... from data D where NEW.number between D.number+1 and D.number+D.max_number and expire_time>now() and 4>(select count(1) from таблица_куда_идет_вставка_результатов R where R.user_id=...)`

Answer (score 0):

Почитал комменты и раз никто не предлагает толковый `SQL` вариант, решил предложить альтернативный.

Мыслил из логики , что для такого решения все равно придется делать фулскан и база будет дико напрягаться (учитывая что значений может быть по `500 000`) то возможно стоит просто посчитать все средствами PHP?

Предположим будет 2 файла куда будут постоянно пулится новые значения и эти значения постоянно обсчитывать. Попробовал просто пробежать оба эти массива, все хорошо считается но когда в обоих массивах становится более чем по `10000` записей время выполнения уходит за 1 минуту и это не вариант. Тогда я решил распаралелить вычисления, отправляя в каждую отдельную нить по `1000` операций и при таком подходе получается достаточно быстро :

```
    [time] => 16.2991 ms
    [memory] => 165.25 mb
```

Тестовые массивы по 100000 уникальных записей, на большее у меня просто не хватило мощностей. (`Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz` , `MemTotal: 2097152 kB`)

```
//Так как в вычислениях участвуют только id, number, mNumber - упростил структуру массивов
$data = [
    [11 , 8]
];
$users =[
    11 => 11.17
];

//Добавим тестово по 100000 записей в каждый массив
for($i=0;$i<=100000;$i++){
    $users[$i] = rand(0,100);
    $data[] = [$i , rand(0,100)];
}

//что бы не отжирать память юзаю итератор
$users = (new ArrayObject($users))->getIterator();

//соберем массив операций, каждую операцию поиска нужных величин 
//добавлю в отдельное замыкание 
$callbacks = array_map(function($item)use($users){
    return function()use($item , $users){
        list($uId , $mNumber) = $item;
        $number = $users[$uId];
        $min = bcadd($number,1,2);
        $max = bcadd($number,$mNumber,2);
        $result[$uId] = [];

        //бегу по пользователям проверяю условие, 
        //как только собрал 4 значения покидаю цикл
        foreach($users as $id => $int){
            if($int>$min && $int<$max){
                $result[$uId][] = [$id];
            }
            if(count($result[$uId]) >= 4){
                break;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    };
} , $data);

//сгруппирую массив замыканий по 1000 операций 
//(для моего железа самая не напряженная циферка)
$callbacks = array_map(function($calls){
    return function()use($calls){
        $result = array_map(function($call){
            return $call();
        } , $calls);
        //результат вычислений буду укладывать в файл
        file_put_contents('out', json_encode($result).PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
    };
},array_chunk($callbacks , 1000));

// функция которая асинхронно выполнит каждый кусок замыканий
// будем держать постоянно 50 нитей, 
// как только будет освобождаться процесс, 
// буду добавлять новый и так до тех пор пока не посчитаю все
function launchJob(array $callbacks) {
        $maxThreads = 50;
        $execute = 0;
        foreach ($callbacks as $call) {
            $pid = pcntl_fork();
            if ($pid == -1) { 
                   die("could not fork"); 
            } elseif ($pid) { 
                $execute++; 
                if ($execute>=$maxThreads){ 
                    pcntl_wait($status); 
                    $execute--; 
                } 
            } else { 
                $call();
                exit;
            } 
        }
}

launchJob($callbacks);
```

При такой реализации скрипт укладывается в среднем в `17-19 сек` , проц на моем железе греется пиково до 70%, думаю на php 7 вообще будет летать (хотя если написать на node.js или вообще на GO то это не будет вообще замечаться).

Я не знаю детали задачи, но по сути можно написать простенький демон который будет каждую сек слушать размер файлов и если они изменились , проверять не запущен ли скрипт обсчета и если не запущен будет его запускать.