# Запрос mysql на выборку из двух таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две табицы: category и news. Нужно сделать выборку чтобы показывало 5 новостей каждой категори.
Этот запос показывает все новости.

```
SELECT category.category, news.title FROM category, news WHERE news.category_id=category.id
```

А нужно: 
чтобы на сайте выводилось в таком поряде.
пример:

1. Категория1
2. новость 1
3. новость 2
4. новость 3
5. Категория 2
6. новость 1
7. новость 2
8. новость 3
   и так далее...

Comment: Пронумеровать записи в группах, и отобрать записи с номерами не более 5.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ограничить кол-во записей в группе при группировке в MySQL](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600190/%d0%9e%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

```
set @rank = 0;
set @cursec = -1;
select * from (
select s.name sname, e.name ename, 
  (IF (@cursec != s.id,(@rank := 1),(@rank := @rank + 1))) RANK,
  @cursec := s.id CURSEC
from sect s
  left join elem e on e.sec = s.id
order by s.id,e.id
) T where rank <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Одним запросом не получится.
Первым запросом выбираете категории, запоминаете их в список.
Потом идете циклом по этому списку и выбираете новости данной категории с добавлением к запросу `LIMIT 5`. Это ограничит выборку 5 новостями. По какому принципу вы их будете сортировать - дело ваше.
Выводите это всё на страницу.

Comment: Как это "не получится" ? Одним запросом можно все. Есть только "сложно" и "оно того не стоит". http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600190

Answer (score 0):

Выберите все категории и новости в нужном порядке, оберните результат в подзапрос, добавьте к нему счётчик и пронумеруйте новости отдельно для каждой категории, а затем просто оставьте нужные вам.

Пример для `LIMIT 2` (меняйте по своему усмотрению на 5 или любой другой):

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  @newsNum := IF(t.id != @prevCatId, 1, @newsNum + 1) n,
  @prevCatId := t.id
FROM (
  SELECT c.id, c.category, n.title
  FROM _category c
  INNER JOIN _news n ON n.category_id = c.id
  ORDER BY c.id, n.id
) t
INNER JOIN (SELECT @prevCatId := 0, @newsNum := 0) counters
HAVING n < 3;
```

Результат (лишние поля скрыл):

```
1    sport    news 1.1
1    sport    news 1.2
2    cinema   news 2.1
2    cinema   news 2.2
3    music    news 3.1
3    music    news 3.2
```

Для отладки использовал такие временные таблицы:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _category(id int, category char(8))
  SELECT 1 id, 'sport'  category UNION
  SELECT 2 id, 'cinema' category UNION
  SELECT 3 id, 'music'  category
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _news(id int, category_id int, title char(16))
  SELECT 1 id, 1 category_id, 'news 1.1' title UNION
  SELECT 2 id, 1 category_id, 'news 1.2' title UNION
  SELECT 3 id, 1 category_id, 'news 1.3' title UNION

  SELECT 4 id, 2 category_id, 'news 2.1' title UNION
  SELECT 5 id, 2 category_id, 'news 2.2' title UNION
  SELECT 6 id, 2 category_id, 'news 2.3' title UNION

  SELECT 7 id, 3 category_id, 'news 3.1' title UNION
  SELECT 8 id, 3 category_id, 'news 3.2' title UNION
  SELECT 9 id, 3 category_id, 'news 3.3' title
;
```