# MySQL LIMIT with INNER JOIN - несовместим как использовать CASE?

Tags: mysql, join, limit

Доброго дня!

Опять вопрос по `LIMIT` с `JOIN`:

```
SELECT P.*, C.cat_name FROM prods P INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT id, cat_name FROM categories WHERE lvl=0) C
   ON P.for_id=C.id
   ORDER BY C.id
```

[Полигон](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82658b/1)

Есть две таблицы - категории и товары в них. Код выше (убогий, я понимаю) отбирает товары из категорий высшего порядка `(lvl=0)` с именами этих категорий.

И у меня вопрос - как (и где???) прописать в этом коде `LIMIT=2`, чтобы вывести по два, к примеру, последних товара из каждой категории с `lvl=0`?

UPD: добавлено поле `q` в таблицу категорий. В нем количество товара. Можно же как то задавать переменную, равную `q-2`, по достижении чего MySQL начинает следующую итерацию?

[LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82658b/1)

Спасибо.

Comment: Поставленную задачу LIMIT-ом не решить. Пронумеруйте записи в группах по категории (наверное, с помощью переменных), и во внешнем запросе отберите записи с номерами 1 и 2.

Comment: Я не понял, что означает "записи в группах по категории".

Comment: Пробовал сообразить как-то так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126653/mysql-inner-join-with-limit-to-left-table но безрезультатно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ограничить кол-во записей в группе при группировке в MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600190/%d0%9e%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-mysql)

Comment: Думаю... Пытаюсь понять... Спасибо. Ща попробую...

Comment: Что такое вторая единица после запятой: `@num:=if(@man=manufacturer,@num+1,1)`?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3d1b0/34

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154466/mysql-is-there-a-limit-to-innerjoin