# Вывод строк таблицы БД по массиву значений

Tags: mysql

**Как сформировать запрос**, который выведет по две первые строки по sports, it и т.д.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вывод конкретно для данной на скрине таблице должен быть такой:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запрос получился следующего вида: **"SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_category='sports' OR news_category='it' OR news_category='politics'"**  .  Как добавить LIMIT 2 ? Чтобы строк со значениями sports, it, politics было не больше 2?

Comment: А что такое "первые" строки ? в SQL нет понятия порядка строк, пока не указана сортировка в которой они "первые"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ограничить кол-во записей в группе при группировке в MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600190/%d0%9e%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-mysql)

Comment: @Mike но есть же порядок перебора строк в таблице. Мне надо вывести по 2 строки указанных значений. Я так понимаю, будут выводится те, с которых начинается таблица

Comment: порядка перебора не существует. вернее бд _обычно_ берет в том порядке в котором они на диске, но невозможно предсказать, какой порядок окажется на диске. СУБД _имеет право_ при каждом обращении строки возвращать в произвольном порядке, отличным от предыдущего ! конечно вы можете не использовать order by, но тогда мы можем говорить не о "две первые" строки, а о "две случайные"

Answer (score 1):

Предположим ваша таблица:
id || text || news_category

Тогда:

```
select id, `news_category`, text 
from 
(
   select id, `news_category`, text ,
      (@num:=if(@group = `news_category`, @num +1, if(@group := `news_category`, 1, 1))) row_number 
  from table1 t
  CROSS JOIN (select @num:=0, @group:=null) c
  order by `news_category`, id desc, text 
) as x 
where x.row_number <= 2
```

Ответ по мотивам https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results