# Базы данных MySQL , не удается реализовать запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется запрос, я хочу вычислить ай_ди автора, которому соответствует наибольшее количество записей в таблице LIST. Т.е. в LIST author_id может встретиться один и более раз. Я пытаюсь вычислить максимальное количество , затем сравнить его с другим запросом и вывести id , но не получается. Можно ли здесь как-то использовать with? Здесь я обращаюсь к одной и той же таблице

```
SELECT LL.AUTHOR_ID FROM LIST LL
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(LL.AUTHOR_ID)
FROM LIST LL GROUP BY LL.AUTHOR_ID) = 
(SELECT MAX(BNUM) FROM (SELECT COUNT(L.AUTHOR_ID) AS BNUM
FROM LIST L GROUP BY L.AUTHOR_ID));
```

Comment: если надо получить id для которого записей больше всего, от причем тут какой то max(bnum) ? Кроме того, любой подзапрос, который в where проверяется на строгое равенство должен вернуть точно одно значение, а ваши подзапросы содержат group by и таким образом возвращают несколько значений и использовать с ними оператор `=` нельзя. И наконец, ваши подзапросы ни как не зависят от той записи, которая выбирается в данный момент в основном запросе, а следовательно их результат одинаков для всех записей и в итоге вы либо получите вообще все, либо ничего

Comment: А еще укажите, какая СУБД используется. Самым прямым путем получения одного id с масимальным кол-вом будет что то вроде `select author_id from list group by author_id order by count(1) desc limit 1` (или аналогичным limit средством вашей СУБД).

Comment: @Mike, используется MySQL, а order+limit приведет к "Using temporary; Using filesort", даже если author_id индекс. Если бы решалась аналогичная задача над массивом на C или каком-то другом языке, то был бы массив вида {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}, либо {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 2}}, что соответствует наличию индекса. Разве нужен еще один массив, разве нужно его сортировать? Достаточно один раз пробежать циклом. Вот, интересно, как так сделать на SQL.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Что то я вас не понял, откуда тут возьмется отсортированный заранее массив. индекс даст "массив" отсортированный по author_id, но нам то нужно сначала посчитать количества каждого автора, потом полученный массив количеств (по 1 записи на автора) мы сортируем и поэтому получается filesort. На MySQL один проход массива легко эмулируется с помощью переменных. так же как в C считаем +1 на счетчике пока сохраняется автор, и отдельно помним максимум и нужного автора. Что то в этом роде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600200/194569 только с сохранением максимума

Comment: @Mike, массив заранее отсортирован, если используется btree, но даже если используется hash, то одинаковые значения в массиве идут только подряд, то есть, для получения значения с максимальным количеством вхождений все еще требуется лишь один цикл по массиву.

Comment: @Mike, с hash я ошибся, но с btree все, вроде, именно так.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Так с переменными вы именно это и получите. За один проход. И кстати показанный план не говорит обо всем. когда я даю запрос `select max(x) from (select count(1) x from tab group by col) A` никакого filesort в помине нет. но время работы не отличается. И в общем то это дело исключительно оптимизатора, как понять и выполнить ваш запрос. А оптимизатор у MySQL тупой. А вот в Oracle оптимизатор отличает такие нюансы и при получении максимума в плане стоит немного другой order by с меньшей стоимостью

Comment: А что Вы будете делать, если таких авторов - с максимальным количеством,- более чем один?

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за пояснения.