# Помогите составить правильный sql запрос

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Порядок нахождения записей в Б.Д построен указным на скриншоте образом.

[image: Порядок нахождения записей в Б.Д]

Мне нужно вывести  5 строк (с конца) из каждого блока записей с последующей возможностью использовать offset.

Comment: Отдельными запросами или хотите в один все запихнуть?

Comment: укажите какая у вас СУБД, тут надо записи нумеровать, а это по разному делается в разных СУБД. и не ясно как offset должен влиять на выборку, он же будет отрезать те блоки которые первыми идут, так что скорее всего он в принципе тут не применим и все должно решаться через порядковые номера записей

Comment: Использую MySql. Записи нужно вывести 1 запросом.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо вам добрый человек =) после вашего комментария я прям прозрел, пошел перепиливать часть своих запросов... блин и почему я раньше не додумывался нумировать строки при запросе...
p.s. не сарказм, правда, даже в мыслях небыло что так можно =)))

Comment: а что насчёт моего вопроса?

Comment: пробовал сделать  это таким образом: `SELECT * FROM tenders WHERE category_id IN(1, 2, 3) ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT 15` но таким образом выводятся все записи, а мне нужно по 5 записей из каждой категории.

Comment: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_row_number_function/page2.html
вот тут именно ваш вариант рассмотрен =)

Comment: @evseygames У вас все таки mysql ... тогда вам надо что то такое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/600190/194569

Comment: *Использую MySql.* Версия у него есть? И если есть - то какая именно? PS. Если восьмая - Вам крупно повезло...

Comment: Блоков - строго три? значения cat_id фиксированы? или 1-2-3 только для примера? *Мне нужно вывести 5 строк (с конца) из каждого блока записей с последующей возможностью использовать offset.* Уточните порядок - сперва 5 записей из блока 1, потом из блока 2 и т.п.. или сперва все первые, потом все вторые...

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tenders WHERE category_id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
union
SELECT * FROM tenders WHERE category_id = 2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
union
SELECT * FROM tenders WHERE category_id = 3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать 3 отдельных запроса с лимитом 5:

```
(SELECT * FROM tenders WHERE category_id IN(1) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5, 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tenders WHERE category_id IN(2) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5, 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tenders WHERE category_id IN(3) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5, 5)
```

Но в этом случае если в какой-то категории не окажется записей, то выведется не 15 записей, а меньше. Можно еще поиграть с общим лимитом для всего запроса и убрать лимит с 3 запроса. Тогда в случае, если не будет достаточно записей в 1 или 2 категории, то с 3-й выберется больше записей.