# Помогите с запросом MySQL. 100.000 вопрос

Tags: mysql

Имеется две таблицы с одинаковой структурой:
Id int, Type int, Data blob
Нужно во второй таблице выбрать первые 10 записей по каждому Type и изменить случайными данными в полях Data из первой таблицы с такими же Type. 
Можно ли подобное осуществить запросами или нужно использовать циклы?

Comment: количество записей примерно какое в таблицах?

Comment: "первые 10 записей" - по какому принципу сортировать?

Comment: в первой около 100к, во второй 10к

Comment: сортировать по id

Comment: А кол-во уникальных Type примерно какое?

Comment: type - ов около 60

Comment: Сначала сделайте запрос, который выберет из каждой группы с ограничением, примерно так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/600190/194569 после этого его можно join соединять с update что бы тот брал найденные им записи. отдельно сделать запрос по второй таблице, который так же отберет некоторое кол-во записей и пронумерует их подряд, при этом указав сортировку `order by rand()`. после этого такой запрос то же join подклеить к этому update по type и сгенеренным номерам строк.