# Найти четвертую запись при заданном условии

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица userlogs

id -айди логируемой записи

user - айди пользователя

date_create_user- дата регистрации пользователя

result - событие совершенное

date_event - дата события

... иные столбцы

В этой таблице логируются действия пользователя. В result хранится 0 или 1. Мне нужно найти всех пользователей у которых первые 3 записи result = 1, а вот 4 запись этого пользователя равна 0 и мне нужно именно эту 4 запись вывести,где result 0 равен.

Думал как то группировками сделать, но никак не выходит. Привязки к дате создания и дате совершения события тоже не получается. Какой алгоритм тут лучше использовать

Comment: читайте описание меток

Comment: Что такое "первые 3 записи", они первые при какой соритровке и нужны именно когда они первые от всех записей данного пользователя или любые 3 подряд (даже если перед ними были другие 0) для пользователя и последующий 0 подходят

Comment: но в любом случае подойти можно со стороны порядковой нумерации строк по условиям и последующей выборке нужных. Нумерация производится как нибудь так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600200/194569

Answer (score 0):

Тут бы еще дату учесть, и кол-во резалт=1 больше 3

```
Select t0.id, t0.user 
From   userlogs t0
Inner  Join userlogs t1 On t0.user = t1.user And t1.result = 1 And Not t0.id = t1.id
Inner  Join userlogs t2 On t0.user = t2.user And t2.result = 1 And t2.id Not In (t0.id, t1.id)
Inner  Join userlogs t3 On t0.user = t3.user And t3.result = 1 And t3.id Not In (t0.id, t1.id, t2.id)
Where  t0.result = 0
Group By t0.id, t0.user
```

Update: Если может быть больше трех записей с result=1 и еще одна с нулем, то запрос такой:

```
Select t0.id, t0.user 
From   userlogs t0
Inner  Join userlogs t1 On t0.user = t1.user And t1.result = 1 And Not t0.id = t1.id
Inner  Join userlogs t2 On t0.user = t2.user And t2.result = 1 And t2.id Not In (t0.id, t1.id)
Inner  Join userlogs t3 On t0.user = t3.user And t3.result = 1 And t3.id Not In (t0.id, t1.id, t2.id)
Left   Join userlogs t4 On t0.user = t4.user And t4.result = 1 And t4.id Not In (t0.id, t1.id, t2.id, t3)
Where  t0.result = 0
And    t4.id Is Null
Group By t0.id, t0.user
```

Вроде Group By не нужен

Update: запрос с датой

```
Select t0.id, t0.user 
From   userlogs t0
Inner  Join userlogs t1 On t0.user = t1.user And t1.result = 1 And Not t0.id = t1.id
Inner  Join userlogs t2 On t2.date > t1.date And t0.user = t2.user And t2.result = 1 And t2.id Not In (t0.id, t1.id)
Inner  Join userlogs t3 On t3.date > t2.date And t0.user = t3.user And t3.result = 1 And t3.id Not In (t0.id, t1.id, t2.id)
Where  t0.result = 0
And    t0.date > t3.date
Group By t0.id, t0.user
```