# Как сделать сортировку по шаблону в MySQL? (order by pattern (cat1, cat2, cat3; cat1, cat2, cat3; ...)

Tags: mysql, sql, order

Есть модель **"Канал"**

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Есть модель **"Микс"**

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| channel_id          | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| on_channel          | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Каждый микс принадлежит какому либо каналу.

Запрос на вывод всех миксов из канала `1, 5 и 15`:

```
"SELECT `mixes`.* FROM `mixes` WHERE `mixes`.`on_channel` = 1 AND `mixes`.`channel_id` IN (1, 5, 15)"

+------+-------------------------------------+------------+
| id   | title                               | channel_id |
+------+-------------------------------------+------------+
|  879 | It's Disco time! MILO 8             |          5 |
|  882 | ElectroDiscoFunkEklektika           |          1 |
|  891 | Pleasure Pizza                      |          5 |
|  953 | Elite Disco Funk                    |         15 |
|  958 | Special mix for Cottonmouth Podcast |          5 |
|  967 | Disco on the way                    |          1 |
|  998 | okoloDISKO #9 for FLAT.FM           |         15 |
| 1119 | Some Funk For Your Ass              |          5 |
| 1267 | GET PHONKEY WITH YOU                |         15 |
| 1272 | Friendly Vibes Mix                  |          5 |
+------+-------------------------------------+------------+
```

**Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы сортировка была в порядке `channel_id = (1, 5, 15)` итерационно, т.е.**

```
+------+-------------------------------------+------------+
| id   | title                               | channel_id |
+------+-------------------------------------+------------+
|  882 | ElectroDiscoFunkEklektika           |          1 |
|  879 | It's Disco time! MILO 8             |          5 |
|  953 | Elite Disco Funk                    |         15 |
|  967 | Disco on the way                    |          1 |
|  891 | Pleasure Pizza                      |          5 |
|  998 | okoloDISKO #9 for FLAT.FM           |         15 |
|  958 | Special mix for Cottonmouth Podcast |          1 |
| 1119 | Some Funk For Your Ass              |          5 |
| 1267 | GET PHONKEY WITH YOU                |         15 |
| 1272 | Friendly Vibes Mix                  |          1 |
+------+-------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: надо сначала отсортировать по каналу, пронумеровать в пределах канала порядковыми номерами 1,2,3, а потом отсортировать по этим порядковым номерам и номеру канала. В 8 версии mysql нумеровать можно с помощью row_number(). В более ранних версиях с помощью переменных, как в подзапросе в этом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600200/194569 ответе

Comment: @Mike 
1. `"SELECT `mixes`.* FROM `mixes` WHERE `mixes`.`on_channel` = 1 AND `mixes`.`channel_id` IN (1, 5, 15) ORDER BY `channel_id`"
2. пронумеровать в пределах канала порядковыми номерами 1,2,3 -- возникла проблема, не смог по примеру построить запрос
3. отсортировать по этим порядковым номерам и номеру канала -- аналогично пункту 2

Если есть возможность, помогите на моём примере

Comment: Т.е. версия mysql < 8 ?

Comment: @Mike 5.5.9 версия

Comment: ну на 8 очень просто `row_number() over(partition by channel_id order by id)` даст вам номера 1,2,3 в пределах одного канала и если вы по нему отсортируете, то уже получите все 1е записи (всех каналов), потом все 2е и т.п.

Comment: @Mike поспешил я сказать что обновился. На debian 8 это оказалось сделать не так легко. Пока остался на 5.5.9

Comment: @Deepsystm, Если мой ответ Вам помог, обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов

Answer (score 1):

Для MySQL 5.x:

```
SELECT `channel`, `title`
FROM (
  SELECT 
      @row_number:=CASE
          WHEN @channel_id = `channel_id` THEN @row_number + 1
          ELSE 1
      END AS num,
      @channel_id:=`channel_id` as `channel`,
      `title`
  FROM
      `mixes`
  WHERE `on_channel` = 1
    AND `channel_id` IN (1, 5, 15)
  ORDER BY `channel_id`
) `q`
ORDER BY `num`, `channel`
```

Пример на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/232942/14)