# Как получить каждую сотую строку в таблице sql

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь сделать паджинацию для вывода таблицы.
Сейчас делаю так:

```
SELECT 'table_id' FROM 'table' WHERE 'условие' ORDER BY 'table_id' DESC
```

Получаю все table_id и уже потом перебирая их получаю каждый сотый элемент и строю таблицу с пиджинацией.

Но сейчас понял, что в таблице слишком много записей и поиск даже одного поля происходит слишком долго.
Может кто знает как сразу в запросе получить каждый сотый элемент ?

UPD:
Если есть возможность прошу указать пример строки с моими параметрами.

Comment: Получить номера строк при заданной сортировке в CTE, и отобрать цельно-сотые.

Comment: Вопрос как раз состоял в том, как написать такую строку.

Comment: А mysql какой версии ? Если до 8 то нумеровать строки может как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600200/194569 (соответственно в внешнем запросе условие будет num % 100 = 0). Если 8 версия, то для нумерации можно использовать row_number()

Comment: А как вы, собственно, строите пагинацию? 
В sql для таких целей есть така штука, как `FOUND_ROWS()`... Минус - запрос всегда будет выполняться полностью, но это лучше чем выбирать каждую сотую запись...

Comment: @InDevX *В sql для таких целей есть така штука, как FOUND_ROWS()* СтОит ли упоминать нестандартную возможность, которая уже выпиливается? *это лучше чем выбирать каждую сотую запись.* Позвольте не согласиться. LIMIT с высокими значениями offset - известный тормоз.

Comment: @Akina тот же "известный тормоз" прилично ускоряется lookup'ом.. но насчет устаревшей фичи да, согласен, читал что с 8.0.что-то-там устарел, будут убирать.. но упоминать стоит, тут вообще всё зависит от проекта и задачи в целом (индексы, все дела.. )