# Как реализовать запрос c Row_Number в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Как реализовать ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY row1, row2 ORDER BY row3) с двумя поля в PARTITION BY, как пример:

```
SELECT
    iv.InvVenPK,
    iv.invPK,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY a.invPK, a.FacPK
        ORDER BY a.AcSt desc, a.Pri
    ) AS RN
FROM ( 
    SELECT invPK, FacPK
    FROM table
    WHERE VenPK = '.....'
    GROUP BY invPK, FacPK
) AS b
JOIN table AS a
ON b.invPK = a.invPK
   AND (
       a.FacPK = b.FacPK
       OR ( 
           a.FacPK IS NULL                  
           AND b.FacPK IS NULL
       )
   )
```

Comment: write in russian please with more providing information

Comment: Тут главный акцент, как реализовать  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY row1, row2 ORDER BY row3)  с двумя поля в PARTITION BY. С одним полем проблем нету, а с двумя не получается

Comment: @ScalandiS на русский переведите, иначе вопрос закроют.

Comment: Примерно как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600200/194569 А два поля от одного ничем не отличаются, представьте что это одно поле `concat(invPK, '-', FacPK)`

Comment: Работаю на одинаковых данных, в MS SQL row_number дает один датасет, в MySQL - другой (запрос переписал как в примере)

Comment: Всем спасибо, советы пригодились, ответ как у @Mike нашел и здесь qaru.site/questions/6092/rownumber-in-mysql