# Оптимальный способ группировки данных в запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

Извиняюсь, тут за свою лень или тупость в праздник дня победы, однако вынужден прибегнуть к помощи своих коллег. Есть таблица article с полями  id|article_text и связанная таблица comment_article id|code_art|code_user|text. Цель вывести статьи блога с комментариями пользователей (самые три последние комментария у каждого блога).

Формирую запрос таким образом:

```
SELECT * FROM `article` as art  
JOIN `comment_article` ca ON ca.code_art IN
(
        SELECT `id`, COUNT(code_art) 
        FROM `comment_art`            
        GROUP BY code_art 
        HAVING COUNT(code_art) < 4                         
) Group By code_art;
```

Либо так:

```
SELECT * FROM `comment_article` as tm1  
JOIN (
        SELECT `id`, COUNT(code_art) 
        FROM `comment_article`            
        GROUP BY code_art 
        HAVING COUNT(code_art) < 4                         
     ) c 
ON tm1.id = c.id                     
Group By code_art;
```

Все не так выполняет работу, что идеи переписать запрос с конструкцией LIMIT, без HAVING наталкивается на проблему низкой версии MySQL, она у меня 5.6. Помогите правильно составить запрос, чтобы сгруппировать записи комментариев у каждой статьи, учитывая, что комментариев может и не быть, либо они напротив их может быть очень много. Изначально мне казалось это легкой задачей, однако, кажется давно не практиковался в многоуровневых запросах, потому забыл... Использование подпрограмм тоже тут мне, кажется, нецелесообразным.

Comment: `LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0` не работает?

Comment: Я в прошлом вашем вопросе давал ссылку на ответ с чуть ли ни единственным способом это сделать в Вашей версии MySQL ( https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/600190/194569 ). Что же касается Вашего текущего варианта - он в принципе не работоспособен. group by code_art дает строго одну запись для одного code_art (группировка для того и предназначена). having накладывает ограничение на всю группу целиком, что бы группы в которых более 4 записей вообще не выводились> И наконец использовать с таким group by поле id вообще нельзя, так как будет выдано первое попавшееся значение ни к чему не относящиеся

Comment: Пример не подходящий на самом деле. Смысл тут не пронумеровать элементы запроса, а сгруппировать их в виде информативных блогов и комментариев.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from article as art 
  left join (
     SELECT comment_article.*, @rank := CASE
         WHEN @partval = code_art THEN @rank + 1
         WHEN (@partval := code_art) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
       END AS rnum
     FROM comment_article, (SELECT @rank := NULL, @partval := NULL) AS x
     ORDER BY code_art, id
  ) ca on ca.code_art = art.id
where ca.id is null or ca.rnum < 4
order by art.id, ca.id
```

описание таблиц с данными и примеры sql-запросов тут -> [DB<>FIDDLE MySQL 5.6](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8ed863212ddcb2f227844c3562af48bb)

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно великолепно! Высший пилотаж с конструкциями, какие только возможны в MySQL 5 версии)