# Как при группировке записей ограничить вывод

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, варианты, как можно ограничить вывод при группировке по количеству записей.
Например, у меня есть таблица вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я бы хотел при группировке с помощью Group by ограничить вывод в группу, например, 3 записями с максимальными платежами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, лайфхаки, как можно ограничить количество строк в каждой группе.
По ощущениям, это можно сделать, с помощью переменных, как в этом примере [Ограничить кол-во записей в группе при группировке в MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600190/%d0%9e%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-mysql)
Но вдруг есть альтернативные более простые решения.

Comment: CTE. ROW_NUMBER(). PS. *я бы хотел при группировке с помощью Group by ограничить вывод в группу, например, 3 записями с максимальными платежами.* То, что Вы показываете на скриншоте 2, никакого отношения к GROUP BY не имеет.

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 и позже.

[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9927666921b0adaeaf01a272451de2b6)

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (server VARCHAR(20), payment INT);

INSERT INTO tbl (server, payment)
VALUES
('alpha', 87),
('alpha', 83),
('alpha', 82),
('alpha', 36),
('beta', 89),
('beta', 74),
('beta', 42),
('beta', 34);

WITH rs (server, payment, seq) AS
(
    SELECT * 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY server ORDER BY payment DESC) AS seq
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT * 
FROM rs
WHERE seq <= 3;
```