# LIMIT вместе с IN как реализовать что бы выводились ограниченное количество строк по каждому ID

Tags: mysql

Искал в интернете и не нашел. Увидел только пример с sql, но я его не понял!
Вот пример таблицы:

| tag_name | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| name | 1 |
| name | 1 |
| name | 1 |
| name | 1 |
| name | 2 |
| name | 2 |
| name | 2 |
| name | 2 |
| name | 2 |
| name | 2 |

Пример запроса:

```
SELECT tag_name, tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag_id IN(1,2) LIMIT 2
```

**И вывод вот такой**:

| tag_name | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| name | 1 |
| name | 1 |

**А нужно**:

| tag_name | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| name | 1 |
| name | 1 |
| name | 2 |
| name | 2 |

И я вообще не знаю, возможно ли вообще так сделать с LIMIT и IN? Прошу от вас помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` "отрезает" указанное количество строк из полученного результата. Для вашего случая необходимо немного более сложно решение, использующее `UNION` (склейку результатов):

```sql
(SELECT tag_name, tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag_id = 1 LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT tag_name, tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag_id = 2 LIMIT 2)
```

Скобки нужны для группирования запроса. Что бы `LIMIT`'ы запросов участвовали только в рамках подзапросов.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает. Конечно же придется постараться если у меня неизвестное количество id.

Comment: @Komend, можно автоматизировать сборку запроса для любого количества `id`. Строки запросов всегда одинаковы, меняется только значение `id`.

Comment: @Komend Для произвольного количества id можно сделать так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600200/194569 (ваш tag_id вместо manufacturer, условие с IN во внутреннем подзапросе). Для mySql 8 вместо переменных можно использовать row_number() с ним проще выглядит

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое за ответ! Буду использовать если что.